# How to properly display a Wordpress featured image URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Newbie here. I am able to display the Wordpress featured image URL and use it as a background through this code:

```html
<header class="<?php x_masthead_class(); ?>" role="banner" <?php if ( is_single() ) : echo 'style="background-image: url(\'';  echo the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); echo '\');"'; endif; ?> >
```

But when I try this method:

```html
<header class="<?php x_masthead_class(); ?>" role="banner" <?php if ( is_single() ) : echo 'style="background-image: url(\'';  echo the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); echo '\');"'; endif; ?> >
```

I get a different result where the image URL does not display right after the **background-image: url('**. It displays before it and the URL displays spaces instead of **/**.

I know I might be missing something in this. I have tried googling around but I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The function `the_post_thumbnail_url` print the URL, so you don't need the `echo` instruction. So I suggest this line instead:

```
<header class="<?php x_masthead_class(); ?>" role="banner"<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?> style="background-image: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>');" <?php endif; ?> >
```